# General Formula for solutions of the restriction system $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

Is there general formula for the find non-negative solutions of the following system
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k=n$$
such that $x_1\leq r_1 , \cdots,x_k\leq r_k$ and $0\leq n\leq r_1+r_2+\cdots +r_k$?

I could find  closed formula for the solutions of the following system 
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_k=n$$
with restriction $x_i\leq r$. It is equal
$$
\sum_{t=0}^k(-1)^t\binom kt\binom{n-t(r+1)+k-1}{k-1}\;,
$$
(with [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)).

For example, How can find solutions of the system 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=k$$
Such that $x_1\leq \alpha, x_2\leq \beta$ and $x_3\leq \gamma$

Comment: You essentially do the same thing, just that your formula would have $2^k$ terms instead.

Comment: I think , First, I have to find solution with $x_1\leq r_1$ and then $x_2\leq r_2$ and so on.

Comment: It's sightly easier to apply PIE to cases where $ x_i \geq r_i$, because then you use the substitution of $x_i ' = x_1 - r_i$, and subtract that from all cases. Some related questions on the right are helpful, like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936496/using-inclusion-exclusion-to-solve-x-1x-2x-3-15-with-x-1-x-2-leq-5-and-x?rq=1)

Comment: Right, is it impossible find solution by generating function?

Comment: It is possible, but it doesn't have a "nice" solution that doesn't require you to eventually expand it out.