# Numbers of ways to choose $k$ out of the first $n$ natural numbers so the longest string of consecutive numbers is exactly $m$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can $k$ numbers be chosen from the first $n$ natural numbers so that the longest string of consecutive numbers is exactly $m$ numbers long

For example, if choosing $k = 7$ distinct numbers from the first $n = 14$ natural numbers ($1-14$), how many combinations of numbers are there that have *exactly* $m = 3$ consecutive numbers?

Some sets that satisfy this would be $[1,2,3,5,7,10,13]$, $[1,2,3,7,8,10,11]$, or $[1,2,3,6,9,10,11]$.

Obviously $m \le k \le n$, and the order of the numbers picked does not matter, but there is no repetition, so $[1,2,3]$ is the same as $[2,1,3]$, but $[1,1,3]$ is not allowed.

For cases when $m \gt \frac k2$ I believe the equation 
$$2* \binom {n-m-1}{k-m} + (n-m-1)*\binom{n-m-2}{k-m}$$

will produce the correct answer, but for values of $m \le \frac k2$ I do not know how to account for multiple strings of consecutive digits in the same set (eg. $[\textbf{1,2,3},6,\textbf{8,9,10}]$) not being counted twice.

---

If anyone could give me help with this example that I could extrapolate from or (ideally) a formula or any references to solve for a general case it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I posted an answer, but then looked back at your question and realized that I didn't understand it completely.  When you say the selection has exactly $m$ consecutive numbers, do you mean there is exactly one string of $m$ consecutive numbers but that there may also be other consecutive strings that are shorter?

Comment: Yes. The way I meant it was that there may be other strings that are shorter, so for example if $n=10$, $k=7$, and $m=3$ you could have $[1,2,3, 5,6,7,9]$ which would have multiple strings of length $m$ or $[1,3,4,5,7,8,10]$ which would have one string of length $m$ but also other shorter strings of consecutive numbers. However, you could not have $[1,2,4,5,6,7,9]$ because that has a string of length greater than $m$.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that what I wrote could have been interpreted differently than what I meant. Instead of exactly one string of length $m$, I meant that there could be multiple strings, but none longer than length $m$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this; I think we misinterpreted the question because of the way the title is worded.

Comment: ok, but then amend your post, not to compel to go through the comments !

Comment: @GCab I deleted my original post when I realized this, and posted a different answer instead.

Comment: Good, that sounds better. With standard terminology you are speaking of *k-subsets from set $\{1,2,\cdots , n\}$ which contains ...*. It's a very interesting problem I am trying to work out.

Comment: and I could work it out: hope my answer is satisfactory to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $l=n-k$, and line up $l$ sticks (representing the numbers not chosen).

If we let $x_i$ represent the number of integers in gap $i$, the number of choices with no string longer than $m$ is given by the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_{l+1}=k\;$ with $0\le x_i\le m$ for each $i$,

so there are $\displaystyle s_1=\binom{n}{l}-\binom{l+1}{1}\binom{n-(m+1)}{l}+\binom{l+1}{2}\binom{n-2(m+1)}{l}-\cdots$ such choices.

To count the number of choices with at least one string of length $m$, we can subtract the number of choices with no string longer than $m-1$, which is given by the number of solutions of

$\hspace{.2 in}x_1+\cdots+x_{l+1}=k\;$ with $0\le x_i\le m-1$ for each $i$,

so there are $\displaystyle s_2=\binom{n}{l}-\binom{l+1}{1}\binom{n-m}{l}+\binom{l+1}{2}\binom{n-2m}{l}-\cdots$ such choices.

Then there are $\displaystyle s_1-s_2=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k}{m}\rfloor}(-1)^{j+1}\binom{l+1}{j}\left[\binom{n-jm}{l}-\binom{n-j(m+1)}{l}\right]$ possibilities.

---

(I am using the nonstandard convention that $\dbinom{r}{l}=0$ if $r<l$.)

Comment: This still isn't working for me. I'll be honest, I don't quite understand how you got the equations for $s_1$ and $s_2$. But also, the stopping point for the summation ($\lceil\frac{2k-n}{m}\rceil$) doesn't really seem to work because if $k \lt \frac m2$ it goes to zero and the summation returns 0 een if we know this is wrong.

Comment: @corndog I think these answers might help:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429561  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904734                                            (I may not have the stopping point for the summation right, but I think it's correct.)

Comment: Thanks so much for those links, I admittedly know very little about combinatorics, so just reading all of this is slowly starting to make it all come together for me

Comment: This is wrong in a few ways. Firstly in the $s_1$ and $s_2$ expressions I see you're using inclusion exclusion to count the number but $\binom{k-(m+1)}{l}$ is not how many ways you have to distribute the remaining $k-(m+1)$ integers in the gaps and even if it was it counts some possibilities twice (For example if k=6 and m=2, you could choose your gap of 3 to be in gap 1 and then distribute the remaining 3 all in gap 2 or you could choose your gap of 3 to be in gap 2 and then distribute the remaining 3 all in gap 1 and these are counted differently).

Comment: Then when you come to work out an expression for $s_1 - s_2$ the limit of your summation is wrong due to the fact $\binom{k-jm}{l}$ is wrong (if $2k\le n$ you have to sum between 1 and 0). Also it is possible for $s_1$ and $s_2$ to have a different number of terms and so putting them in the same summation is impossible.

Comment: @PJF49 I don't understand your comments, but if you give a specific example where this gives the wrong answer, that would be helpful.

Comment: Okay examples, if n=2, k=1 and m=1 the possible s

Comment: If $n=2, k=1, m=1$ the possible subsets are $[1]$ and $[2]$ whereas your formula gives $\sum_{j=1}^{0}(-1)^{j+1}\binom{l+1}{j}\left[\binom{k-jm}{l}-\binom{k-j(m+1)}{l}\right]$ which isn't defined as the upper limit is less than the lower limit. Even worse if $n=3, k=1, m=1$ there are three possible subsets but in your formula the upper limit is $-1$. Even if the upper limit is positive it still doesn't work. For example if $n=3, k=2, m=2$ the possible subsets are $[1,2]$ and $[2,3]$ whereas your formula gives $\binom{2}{1}\left[\binom{0}{1}-\binom{-1}{1}\right]$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: If $n=5,k=3,m=2$ the possible subsets are $[1,2,4], [1,2,5], [2,3,5], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [2,3,5]$. However your formula gives $\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil\frac{6-5}{2}\rceil}(-1)^{j+1}\binom{2+1}{j}\left[\binom{3-2j}{2}-\binom{3-3j}{2}\right] = \binom{3}{1}\left[\binom{1}{2}-\binom{0}{2}\right]$ which is also wrong.

Comment: @PJF49 Thank you for these examples -- this helped me find a typo in my formula, and a mistake in the upper limit.

Comment: Okay it seems your solution now works and some of bits I said were wrong were actually right, it took me a while to work out what some of the terms were doing (sorry about that). Your solution is now very nice, I wish I'd thought of some of it.

Comment: I saw your amended formula after I posted mine. The results coincides (apart that your formula gives 0 for the case n=k) (+1)

Comment: @user84413 in the final function, should the two expressions in the brackets $\binom{n-jm}{l}$ and $\binom{n-j(m+1)}{l}$ be switched? What you have appears to be $s_2-s_1$

Comment: also could you explain how you got the stopping point of $\lfloor{\frac km}\rfloor$

Comment: @corndog I believe the expression given equals $s_1-s_2$, because of the alternating signs in both sums.  I found the upper limit for the sum by solving $n-jm<l$, where $l=n-k$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I had just flipped the powers for $(-1)$, (I had $(-1)^j$ not $(-1)^{j+1}$ so everything was coming out negative.

Answer (score 1):

Another more practical solution uses a recurrence relation. Let the size of the gaps between the $n-k$ numbers not chosen be $x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-k+1}$. Then the problem reduces to how many ways are there such that $\forall i$, $x_i\in [0,1...m]$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}x_i = k$ and at least one of $x_i = m$.

To solve this first consider the solutions of another similar problem, $\forall i$, $x_i\in [0,1...m]$, $\sum_{i=1}^{y}x_i = k$ where the constraint at least one of $x_i = m$ doesn't exist and $n-k+1$ has been replaced by $y$. Let the number of solutions of this problem be the function $S(y,k,m)$. Next consider removing the last $x_i$ in a solution of $y,k,m$. Then the remaining $x_i$ will give us a solution of $y-1,k-a,m$ for some $a\in [0,1...m]$. Therefore $S(y,k,m) = \sum_{a=0}^{m}S(y-1,k-a,m)$. $S(1,k,m) = 1$ iff $k\in [0,1...m]$ which allows us to tabulate all other values.

For example in the $m=2$ case:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline \text{y\k} & \text{0} & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4} & \text{5} & \text{6} & \text{7} & \text{8} & \text{9} & \text{10} \\ 
\hline \text{1} & \text{1} & \text{1} & \text{1} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} \\
\hline \text{2} & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{2} & \text{1} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} \\
\hline \text{3} & \text{1} & \text{3} & \text{6} & \text{7} & \text{6} & \text{3} & \text{1} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} & \text{0} \\
\hline \text{4} & \text{1} & \text{4} & \text{10} & \text{16} & \text{19} & \text{16} & \text{10} & \text{4} & \text{1} & \text{0} & \text{0} \\
\hline \text{5} & \text{1} & \text{5} & \text{15} & \text{30} & \text{45} & \text{51} & \text{45} & \text{30} & \text{15} & \text{5} & \text{1} \\
\hline \end{array}$$

Then let $P(y,k,m)$ be the number of solutions of the problem with the constraint at least one of $x_i = m$ included. $P(y,k,m) = S(y,k,m) - S(y,k,m-1)$.

For example $P(3,3,2) = S(3,3,2) - S(3,3,1) = 7-1 = 6$ (with $S(3,3,1)$ quickly worked out by hand).

Therefore the number of solutions of the original problem with $n=5, k=3, m=2$ is $P(5-3+1,3,2) = P(3,3,1) = 6$ and as the possible solutions of this problem are $[1,2,4], [1,2,5], [2,3,5], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [2,3,5]$ this is indeed correct.

Although this is a bit time consuming by hand it should be possible to get a computer to use the recurrence relation to generate the solutions.

Comment: I quite like this idea, as it is a lot more practical and straightforward. It's a shame though that it involves so much backtracking to produce a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

So we can arrange the $k$ choosen numbers in order, and therefore we are speaking of *k-subsets from the set* $\{1,\cdots , n\}$.

Let's
 - put a $0$ in front of the subset (sequence);
 - take the backward differences;
 - neglecting the first ($=a_1$), consider the differences from the 2nd to $k$-term.
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & 0,a_{\,1} ,a_{\,2} , \cdots ,a_{\,k} \quad \left| {\;1 \le j \le a_{\,j}  \le n} \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  & \;a_{\,1} ,a_{\,2}  - a_{\,1} , \cdots ,a_{\,k}  - a_{\,k - 1}  = a_{\,1} ,d_{\,2} , \cdots ,d_{\,k} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad d_{\,2} ,d_{\,3} , \cdots ,d_{\,k} \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;2 \le j \hfill \cr 
  \;1 \le d_{\,j}  = a_{\,j}  - a_{\,j - 1}  \le n - 1 \hfill \cr 
  \;1 \le \sum\limits_{2\, \le \,j\, \le \,k} {d_{\,j} }  = q = a_{\,k}  - a_{\,1}  \le n - 1 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
 } \tag{1}$$

Then we are looking for the
number of (*standard*) compositions of $0 \le q \le n-1$ into $1 \le k-1 \le n-1$ parts , each positive (and no greater than $n-1$) , that contain *runs of contiguous ones no longer than $0 \le m-1$*.
We will take for the moment the cumulative version "runs no longer than", and will later manage to get the version "runs with max length equal to".

For $k=1$, the above scheme does not apply, but for subsets with one element ,clearly, the number of contiguous elements is $1$,
and there are $n$ possible subsets.
For $2 \le k$, the same value of $q=a_{k}-a_{1}$ can be attained in $n-q$ ways, and the result shall be summed over $1 \le q \le n-1$.

It is known that the number of compositions of $q$ into $k$ parts is
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N_{\,s\,c} (q,k) = \left[ {1 \le q} \right]\left( \matrix{
  q - 1 \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)
 } \tag{2.a}$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

We can part this quantity according to the number of ones that it contains, denoted by $0\le s \le k$, as
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & N_{\,s\,cs} (q,k,s) = \left[ {k = q} \right]\left[ {k = s} \right] + \left[ {k + 1 \le q} \right]\left( \matrix{
  q - k - 1 \cr 
  k - s - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  s \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\left[ {k = q} \right]\left[ {k = s} \right] + \left[ {k + 1 \le q} \right]\left( \matrix{
  q - k - 1 \cr 
  k - s - 1 \cr}  \right)} \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  s \cr}  \right) \cr} 
 } \tag{2.b}$$
where the second term (${{k} \choose {s}}$) corresponds to the number of binary string $(1,\cdots,X,\cdots)$ 
obtained by replacing with $X$ the parts greater than one, and the first factor to the number of ways to compose the $X$s.

Coming to the binary string, clearly we can change the $X$ with a $0$, then
the number of binary strings of a given length , number of ones, and max length of runs of ones
is extensively treated [in this other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045496/number-of-occurrences-of-k-consecutive-1s-in-a-binary-string-of-length-n-conta/2045737#2045737).

From there we have that  the
*Number of binary strings, with $s$ ones , $m$ zeros and runs of ones which are not longer than $r$*
 is given by
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N_b (s,r,m + 1)\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers  }\,s,m,r} \right.\quad  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\,\left( { \le \,{s \over r}\, \le \,m + 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \matrix{
  m + 1 \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  s + m - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr 
  s - j\left( {r + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)} 
 }\tag {3.a}$$

Translating that into into our case, the number of
 *binary strings with  length $k$ and $s$ ones and runs of ones no longer than $m$* is
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & N_b (s,m,k + 1 - s)\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integers  }\, s,m,k  - s} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {\;0 \le s} \right]\left[ {\;0 \le m} \right]\left[ {\;s  \le k} \right]\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\,\left( { \le \,\,k - s + 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \matrix{
  k + 1 - s \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k - j\left( {m + 1} \right) \cr 
  s - j\left( {m + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
 } \tag{3.b}$$

Going back through the steps above, the
*Number of composition of $q$, with length $k$ , number of ones $s$ and runs of ones no longer than $m$* 
will be the above multiplied by the first factor in (2.b)
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & N_{\,c\,q\,s}  = (q,k,s,m)\quad \left| {\;{\rm integers  }q,s,m,k} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\left[ {k = q} \right]\left[ {k = s} \right] + \left[ {k + 1 \le q} \right]\left( \matrix{
  q - k - 1 \cr 
  k - s - 1 \cr}  \right)} \right)N_b (s,m,k - s + 1) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\left[ {k = q} \right]\left[ {k = s} \right] + \left[ {k + 1 \le q} \right]\left( \matrix{
  q - k - 1 \cr 
  k - s - 1 \cr}  \right)} \right)\; \cdot   \cr 
  &  \cdot \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,\,j\,\,\left( { \le \,\,k - s + 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \matrix{
  k + 1 - s \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k - j\left( {m + 1} \right) \cr 
  s - j\left( {m + 1} \right) \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
 } \tag{4}$$

Therefore, the
*number of k-subsets from the set* $\{1,\cdots , n\}$ *having no more than* $m$ *contiguous characters*
is
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & N_{c\,u\,m} (n,k,m) = \left[ {1 = k} \right]\left[ {1 \le m} \right]n +   \cr 
  &  + \left[ {2 \le k} \right]\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,q\, \le \,n - 1} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s\, \le \,k} {\left( {n - q} \right)N_{\,c\,q\,s} (q,k - 1,s,m - 1)} }  \cr} 
 } \tag{5.a}$$

Finally, the number of k-subsets with one or more run of contiguous elements
of length $m$, and none longer will clearly be
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
N_{c\,u\,m} (n,k,m)-N_{c\,u\,m} (n,k,m-1)
 } \tag{5.b}$$